# Saving local Enterprise Architect project settings to database server

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is it possible to save the local Sparx Enterprise Architect project preferences (Start > Preferences) to the database server?

We share the project through a database and have changed some settings for the project which seem to not be saved to the database and I suspect they are only saved in the local Windows registry.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of preferences in EA:

### User preferences

- Accessed through **Start | Appearance | Preferences**
- Most of these settings are stored in the registry: **Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\OPTIONS**

### Model preferences

- Accessed through **Settings | Model | Options**
- These settings are stored in the repository itself.

**EA does not support setting users settings on a model level out of the box.**

### Solution using EA-Matic

[EA-Matic](https://bellekens.com/ea-matic/) is a free open source add-in written by myself.
It supports executing scripts as a reaction to events such as `EA_FileOpen()`
This script below is used in order to ensure every user of the repository has these same settings.

It basically checks a number of registry values, and updates them if needed. Because EA only reads the registry when starting up, the script closes EA when it has updated a setting, asking the user to restart it.

```
'[path=\Projects\EA-Matic Scripts]
'[group=EA-Matic]
option explicit

!INC Local Scripts.EAConstants-VBScript

'
' Script Name: Fix Mandatory User Settings
' Author: Geert Bellekens
' Purpose: Check the mandatory user settings in the registry and set them correctly if needed
' Date: 2019-11-05
'

'EA-Matic

const REG_SZ = "REG_SZ"
const REG_DWORD = "REG_DWORD"
const REG_BINARY = "REG_BINARY"

function fixSettings
    dim regPath
    Dim regkey
    dim regValue
    dim existingValue
    'place in the registry that contains all of the user settings
    regPath = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\EA400\EA\OPTIONS\"
    'get the EA version
    dim eaVersion
    eaVersion = Repository.LibraryVersion
    
    dim settingsValid
    settingsValid = true
    'Fontname13 is only relevant for V15
    if eaVersion > 1300 then
        settingsValid = settingsValid AND validateRegValue(regPath, "FONTNAME13","Arial", REG_SZ)
    else
        settingsValid = settingsValid AND validateRegValue(regPath, "FONTNAME","Arial", REG_SZ)
    end if
    settingsValid = settingsValid AND validateRegValue(regPath, "SAVE_CLIP_FRAME","1", REG_DWORD)
    settingsValid = settingsValid AND validateRegValue(regPath, "PRINT_IMAGE_FRAME","1", REG_DWORD)
    settingsValid = settingsValid AND validateRegValue(regPath, "SAVE_IMAGE_FRAME","1", REG_DWORD)
    settingsValid = settingsValid AND validateRegValue(regPath, "SORT_FEATURES","0", REG_DWORD)
    settingsValid = settingsValid AND validateRegValue(regPath, "ALLOW_DUPLICATE_TAGS","1", REG_DWORD)
    
    if not settingsValid then
        msgbox "Mandatory user settings have been corrected." & vbNewLine & "Please restart EA",vbOKOnly+vbExclamation,"Corrected mandatory user settings!" 
        Repository.Exit
    end if
        
end function

function validateRegValue(regPath, regKey, regValue, regType)
    Dim shell
    ' Create the Shell object
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    dim existingValue
    on error resume next
    'read registry value
    existingValue = shell.RegRead(regPath & regkey)
    'if the key doesn't exist then RegRead throws an error
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        existingValue = ""
        Err.Clear
    end if
    on error goto 0
    'check the value in the registry with the desired value
    if Cstr(existingValue) <> regValue then
        'write the correct value to the registry
        shell.RegWrite regPath & regkey, regValue, regType
        'return false
        validateRegValue = false
    else
        'value was already OK, return true
        validateRegValue = true
    end if
end function

function EA_FileOpen()
     fixSettings
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Geerts excellent answer I would like to add that you can alter the registry location for the options (which go to registry and not to the database) by supplying an option to the command line when you open EA.

E.g. if you invoke EA with

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\EA\EA.exe" /regkey:P1
```

it will create/access the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sparx Systems\P1` rather than `\EA400` which is the default.

[image]

The options itself are found under the `OPTIONS` key below.

This gives you the opportunity to handle different settings out of the box. At least for those options Sparx decided to go to the registry rather than the database. (Editor's note: It will be an options jungle in any case)

Comment: I took the freedom to edit you answer. This was new to me and most likely I will add this to my Inside EA book ;-) So thanks!